# Populating listview with instances from Realm database

Tags: android

Please who can help me out on how to populate a list view with instances from realm un android. I am am new to android developments.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an adapter and set it to the listview.
More info at: [Create adapter for ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)